# Stop Locust When Specified Number Of User Tasks Complete

Tags: locust

In my scenario, I'm running Locust without the web UI. The command I'm using is

```
locust -f my_locust_file --no_web -c 20 -r 4     # as a hack I add -t 10s
```

This corresponds to a 4 users being hatched every second up to a total of 20 users.

My objective is to have each of the 20 locust users execute a task and I'd like the locust run to complete and exit when the last user's (20th user) task completes.  The collected statistics should only include the response times associated with each task.

In this scenario, 5 tasks (user scenarios) have been identified which can be randomly associated with a user:

```
class UserScenarios(TaskSet):
    tasks = [Sequence_One, ServerSequence, Components_Sequence, Embedded_Sequence, Connectivity_Sequence]

class MyLocust(HttpLocust):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        MyLocust.counter += 1
        print(f"Counter = {MyLocust.counter}")

    counter = 0
    task_set = UserScenarios
    wait_time = between(1, 1)
    host = 'https://*****.com'
```

Each task (user scenario) corresponds to a different sequence of 3 or 4 pages that should be loaded in order. An example sanitized and simplified sequence consisting of 2 pages is:

```
class Sequence_One(TaskSequence):

    @seq_task(1)
    def get_task1(self):
        response = self.client.get(url='https://****',
                                   name='https://****',
                                   timeout=30,
                                   allow_redirects=False,
                                   headers={...})   

    @seq_task(2)
    def get_task2(self):
        response = self.client.get(url='https://****',
                                   name='https://****',
                                   timeout=30,
                                   allow_redirects=False,
                                   headers={...})
```

Is there a way to stop the test after the 20th (nth) user task completes?  If every task visits 4 pages for example, I want the test to terminate after the 20*4 = 80 page request is made.  In fact only 80 total page requests should be made as part of this test.

My experience with this test is that page requests continue to be made after the last user task completes until I either manually stop the test or use a time limit which is a bit longer than the tasks actually need to complete.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is actually possible! While it's not documented, at least anywhere that I could find, stopping a Locust can be achieved by calling 
    raise StopLocust()

In the provided scenario, each of your tasks is a TaskSequence class. In order to quit a Locust after a single task has been performed, you will need to add another step (function) to the overall class which makes a call to StopLocust(). I've provided an example below -

```
class Scenario(TaskSequence):

    @seq_task(1)
    def task_1(self):
        self.client.get("/going_somewhere")

    @seq_task(2)
    def task_2(self):
        self.client.get("/going_somewhere_else")

    @seq_task(3)
    def done(self):
        raise StopLocust()
```

By default, a Locust is set to never end and will continuously pick a task from the available task sets provided to it. Supplying raise StopLocust() will tell the current user (Locust) to stop and no longer pick tasks once it reaches the end of that current task.

Comment: Works great... I completely missed the concept of adding a sequence task to invoke StopLocust... actually I didn't now about StopLocust either. Understanding how the tasks works enables a couple of scenarios I had questions about. Thanks for the reply and answer!

Comment: Doesn't `self.interrupt()` do the same thing too?

Comment: Locust is currently in the process of renaming a lot of things, including [StopLocust into StopUser](https://github.com/locustio/locust/commit/530db29ad7bd3ceda8f9c81f0b585984dd6a1a43) and [TaskSequence into SequentialTaskSet](https://github.com/locustio/locust/commit/cd28b2999a06c6f29c8c83167a44223dd8e52668).

Comment: @SohamDongargaonkar `interrupt` is similar from what I understand, as it stops execution in many cases.  However it leaves open the possibility that more tasks can be scheduled for a given User, which does not seem possible if `StopUser` is raised.

Comment: Looks like `StopLocust` has been removed on locust 1.2, but you can use `locust.exception.StopUser`

Answer (score 3):

use

raise exit()

if you want to make a definite hits create a sequirtial task set and raise exit() raise exit will stop that user

#its a way around as nothing else seen to work for me.

Comment: Hi, this will stop entire locust. Is there any way to stop current user only?

Comment: This should be the accepted answer as it is the only one that works and locust won't be able to break.

Answer (score 3):

You can stop a single user by raising `locust.exception.StopUser` exception:

```
from locust.exception import StopUser

class Scenario(TaskSequence):
    @seq_task(1)
    def task_1(self):
        self.client.get("/going_somewhere")

    @seq_task(2)
    def task_2(self):
        self.client.get("/going_somewhere_else")

    @seq_task(3)
    def done(self):
        raise StopUser()
```

P.S. `StopLocust` exception mentioned in other answers was deprecated in favor of `StopUser` exception.

Answer (score 1):

I use locust 1.3+
StopLocust() is deprecated

My framework creates a list of tuples of the credentials and support variables for every user. I have stored all my user credentials, tokens, support file names etc in those tuples as part of list. (Actually that is automatically done before starting locust)

I import that list in locustfile

```
# creds is created before running locust file and can be stored outside or part of locust # file
creds = [('demo_user1', 'pass1', 'lnla'),
         ('demo_user2', 'pass2', 'taam9'),
         ('demo_user3', 'pass3', 'wevee'),
         ('demo_user4', 'pass4', 'avwew')]

class RegisteredUser(SequentialTaskSet)

    def on_start(self):
        self.credentials = creds.pop()

    @task
    def task_one_name(self):
        task_one_commands

    @task
    def task_two_name(self):
        task_two_commands

    @task
    def stop(self):
        if len(creds) == 0:
            self.user.environment.reached_end = True
            self.user.environment.runner.quit()


class ApiUser(HttpUser):
    tasks = [RegisteredUser]
    host = 'hosturl'
```

I use self.credentials in tasks.
I created **stop** function in my class.

Also, observe that **RegisteredUser** is inherited from **SequentialTaskSet** to run all tasks in sequence.

Answer (score 1):

In headless mode, if you want to stop the whole locust service, you can use `os.kill`

```
class UserTasks(TaskSet):
    @task
    def test_api(self):
        gobal FINISHED_USER, FINISHED_REQUEST
        with self.user.client.post(f"/{api_type}", json=<my data>, headers=<my headers>, catch_response=True) as response:
            # do something
            FINISHED_REQUEST += 1
        if FINISHED_REQUEST == schedule_num:
            # this user finish all its task, will go to on_stop
            self.user._state = "stopping"
            FINISHED_USER += 1
    
    def on_stop(self):
        global FINISHED_USER
        # do something
        # make sure its the last user who finishes its task
        if FINISHED_USER == <your user num>:
            os.kill(<your pid>, signal.SIGTERM)

class WebsiteUser(HttpUser):
    """
    User class that does requests to the locust web server running on localhost
    """
    host = "http://{}".format(<host>)
    wait_time = constant_throughput(1)
    tasks = [UserTasks]
```