# Stop locust after specific number of requests

Tags: python, locust

I am using locust 0.14.4. I am testing a rest api. I want to simulate a scenario where a user will sign in into the application and then make few GET requests. e.g. say I want a user to make 3 GET requests after sign in. I want the user count as 3. In this case, each user should sign-in and make 3 GET request and locust should stop. So a total of 12 request.

I found that previously there was an option -n to specify the number of request, however it is not there in version 0.14.4.

I found a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59832109/stop-locust-when-specified-number-of-user-tasks-complete) However it is not working for me.

Here is my code snippet:

```
class MyTaskSet(TaskSet):

def on_start(self):
    """ on_start is called when a Locust start before any task is scheduled """
    self.login()

def login(self):
    resp = self.client.post("https://" + hostip + "/session", auth=(username, password),verify=False)
    data = json.loads(resp.text)
    global session_id
    session_id = data['value']

@seq_task(1)
def user_workflow(self):
    for i in range(0, 1, 1):
        self.get_counters()
        self.get_providers()
        self.get_metrics()

def get_counters(self):
    self.client.get("/counters",headers={'session-id': session_id, 'Accept': 'application/json',
                              'Content-Type': 'application/json'})

def get_providers(self):
    self.client.get("/providers",headers={'session-id': session_id, 'Accept': 'application/json',
                              'Content-Type': 'application/json'})

def get_metrics(self):
    self.client.get("/metrics",headers={'session-id': session_id, 'Accept': 'application/json',
                              'Content-Type': 'application/json'})
@seq_task(2)
def done(self):
    raise StopLocust()
```

When I try running test with command

```
$locust -f locustfile.py --no-web -c 3 -r 3
```

I get following output:

```
Type                 Name               #reqs 50%

 GET                  /counters         1    840 
 GET                  /metrics          1    470 
 GET                  /providers        1    480 
 POST                 /session          3   1300 

 None                 Aggregated        6   1300
```

What I want to achieve is each user should login and make 3 GET request and locust should stop when the last user issues the third get call. Is there a cleaner way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TaskSquence should be used instead of TaskSet as the super class when using seq_task